# TI CC2650STK - How to activate ZigBee?

Tags: zigbee

I've bought a Texas Instruments CC2650STK SensorTag dev kit to experiment with. It [says on the website](http://www.ti.com/ww/en/wireless_connectivity/sensortag2015/tearDown.html) that I can activate ZigBee by pressing the button for 3 seconds. It doesn't seem to do anything as far as I can tell.

Does anyone have any experience of getting ZigBee working on these devices?

Comment: How do you know whether or not it has activated its ZigBee? What are you expecting it to do?

Comment: I have a Digi Xbee and their Xctu software running, sniffing data. Nothing shows up. However, I couldn't find any documentation on how to activate ZigBee or what Pan id it uses. The only reference is the diagram on the site that says to hold the button for 3 seconds

Answer (score 4):

The CC2650ST supports ZigBee, BLE or 6LowPan. It comes programmed with BLE by default, you need to download the BLE sensor tag app from app store and update the FW to the ZigBee image. This will update to a ZigBee image using BLE. The App has the CC2650 ZigBee image included in it, so you just need the latest app. The ZigBee FW image makes the sensorTag into a ZigBee Temp Sensor, Light Sensor and Switch.

Alternatively you can buy a debug-devpack (http://www.ti.com/tool/CC-DEVPACK-DEBUG) and update to a ZigBee image using SmartRF flash programmer. The FW will need to be built from the ZStack-HomeSDK from www.ti.com/tool/z-stack.

Regards,
TC.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realise that you could re-program OTA. The docs are pretty unclear for the dev kit, which is a shame as it seems a nice bit of kit. I'll give it a try tomorrow! Does the ZigBee FW limit it to those sensors that you've listed? e.g. can't access the accelerometer?

Comment: I was able to do OTA fw upgrade to a Zigbee image but now i completely lost contact with the beacon, it started blinking red...Any idea how to scan zigbee packets now?

Comment: I managed to obtain a [Debug Devpack](http://www.ti.com/tool/CC-DEVPACK-DEBUG) and flashed the following file onto the sensortag: `C:/Program Files (x86)/Texas Instruments/SmartRF Tools/BLE Device Monitor/firmware/cc26xx/CC2650SensorTag_ZigBee_All_v1_01.hex`