# How to flash the TI CC2650STK using a XDS110?

Tags: texas-instruments, firmware

I have a [TI cc2650STK](http://ti.com/sensortag) (a.k.a. Sensortag 2) and a corresponding [Debug DevPack](http://www.ti.com/tool/CC-DEVPACK-DEBUG). I've been trying to follow the [instructions on how to use both together](http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/Debug_DevPack_User_Guide#Using_the_Debug_DevPack_with_the_SmartRF_Flash_programmer_2) (as proposed in [this answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/179029/34218)), but I have not been able to flash the Sensortag.
Every time I try to select the device on the left hand side of *SmartRF Flash Programmer 2* (v1.7.1), an error dialog pops up saying "The selected device could not be identified."

[image: flash programmer error dialog]

As you can see in the screen shot, the Debug DevPack shows up as an XDS110, for which I installed the latest [drivers](http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/XDS_Emulation_Software_Package) (release 6.0.83.1). I also upgraded the Debug Devpack's firmware to v2.2.5.1, as suggested by Flash Progammer's "Help Document".

So far, the only resources I found about this are only vaguely related, and they seem to [suggest that using Flash Programmer 2 v1.6 or above fixes the issue](https://e2e.ti.com/support/wireless_connectivity/bluetooth_low_energy/f/538/p/411555/1472333#1472333) ([2nd source](https://e2e.ti.com/support/wireless_connectivity/zigbee_6lowpan_802-15-4_mac/f/158/p/417358/1484962#1484962)). But in my case this doesn't seem to help.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out, I needed to upgrade to SmartRF Flash Programmer 2 v1.7.**2**, as [suggested here](https://e2e.ti.com/support/wireless_connectivity/bluetooth_low_energy/f/538/p/481105/1733138#1733138).